# Permissions for webcam access through Apache

Tags: apache, permissions, cgi

I am trying to capture an image through a webcam and display it on a webpage but I am getting "permission denied errors"

I am running apache with the following user/group
/etc/apache2/envvars   :

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

In the html code i have the request:

```
myRequest.open("GET", "/cgi-bin/getImage1.cgi", true);
myRequest.send();
```

In /usr/lib/cgi-bin I have the file: getImage1.cgi

```
#!/bin/bash
rm image1.jpg
fswebcam -r 640x400 --no-banner --deinterlace -q -d /dev/video0 --jpeg 95 image1.jpg
```

The file and directories permissions are:

```
In /usr/lib          drwxrwxrwx  2 root     www-data   4096 May 14 19:37 cgi-bin
In /usr/lib/cgi-bin  -rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data   115  May 14 18:51 getImage1.cgi
In /dev              crw-rw----+ 1 root     video      81,0 May 14 18:02 video0
```

User www-data is a member of the following groups:

```
$ id www-data
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),44(video)
```

When i run the web page i get the following error code:

```
rm: cannot remove 'image1.jpg': No such file or directory
Error opening device: /dev/video0
open: Permission denied
Unable to find a source module that can read /dev/video0.
End of script output before headers: getImage1.cgi,
```

The error implies that it is executing the script but that the user does not have sufficient permissions to access the /dev/video0. 
The apache user should be www-data which is a member of both www-data and video groups, so it should have access to the /usr/lib/cgi-bin directory, getImage1.cgi file, and the /dev/video0 webcam.

If I execute the script from the console it runs fine.

I would appreciate if anyone can offer suggestions.

Comment: What are the rights on `/dev` itself?

Comment: I have added the rights on the video device above. owner is root:video. and as indicated I added the www-data user to the video group. the permissions are 660 and it is difficult to change these as they go back to default on reboot.

Comment: I'm talking about `/dev`, not `/dev/video0`. If the user/group is locked out of the folder itself, there's no way he can access `video0`. That would be a weird setup but just checking.

Comment: All /dev devices are root. I added the user www-data to the root group in /etc/group and all works fine now. This will work ok for this setup but i am sure that giving web access root privlidges is not a safe way of administering a system.

Comment: Definitely not... That would basically allow a malicious user to execute anything as root from your web scripts

Comment: So what is the solution here. All /dev devices are root:root. If I change this to allow the web page user (e.g. www-data) to access the camera (/dev/video) then do i have to give them permission to access all /dev devices ?

Comment: I think there's some confusion here. When I asked what are the *permissions* of `/dev` I asked if `/dev` as at least `r-x` for *others*, typically, its rights are `drwxr-xr-x`. If it's already the case, then `www-data` can access any device, provided the specific device has the correct permissions (in this case, you would need at least `r` for others) or is owned by the correct user/group. Also, you *can* permanently change the owner or permissions of a specific device, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72437/how-to-grant-non-root-user-access-to-device-files